# working with the same method of several objects without knowing their type

Tags: c++, class

I have some classes, named c1, c2, ... that all have a function in common named get_value().
now I want to write a function like this:

```
int foo(any_class_type obj){ return process(obj.get_value() ); }
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Provide a templated function maybe?

Comment: could you help me more please?

Comment: I wrote an answer with an example.

Comment: Any chance `c1 `and `c2` inherit from a common base class?

Comment: @user4581301 Do they need to have a common base class actually?

Comment: @user0042 No, but it would make it really easy.

Comment: @user4581301 A template is sufficient and _easy_ enough IMO.

Comment: Do you really mean `process(obj.get_value)`? Or `process(obj.get_value())`?

Comment: @user0042 No argument there, but if polymorphism is already in play, might as well take advantage.

Comment: Off topic: Looks like you could pass by reference `int foo(any_class_type & obj)` and save a copy. Might be further advantages to `int foo(const any_class_type & obj)`.

Comment: obj.get_value() sorry , I will edit it now

Answer (score 1):

Writing a templated function might well do what you want:

```
template<typename any_class_type>
int foo(any_class_type obj){ return process(obj.get_value); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a [function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

```
template<typename T>
int foo(T const&obj)
{
  return obj.getValue();
}
```

or use polymorphism:

```
struct C
{
  virtual int getValue() const = 0;
};

struct C1 : C
{
  int getValue() const override;
};

struct C2 : C
{
  int getValue() const override;
};

int foo(C const&obj)
{
  return obj.getValue();
}
```

or overload your function explicitly for the (some of the) types

```
int foo(C1 const&obj) { return obj.getValue(); }
int foo(C2 const&obj) { return obj.getValue(); }
```

or combine these approaches (when the best match will be picked).

A template allows unrelated object types and tends to generate more efficient code than polymorphic functions, but is header-only and also may result in cumbersome compiler error messages should you call it with an argument that does not have a fitting member `getValue`.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Virtual polymorphism introduces significant overhead, where just templating doesn't.